# What extensions can I buy for sending extra order emails and automate tracking

Tags: orders, extensions, email

I'm looking for an extension or combination of extensions that upon successful purchase sends an email to the warehouse manager who stocks the product,  an email to the website admin, and also to the customer as a receipt of what they bought.

Additonally, I've heard there are ways to automate tracking through certain extensions as well though I haven't the faintest clue where to find this.

Any advice would be greatly appreciate.  Thanks
Wil

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by tracking?

Comment: Hi Vlad what I mean is that when the wharhouse sends out the package to the customer I want the customer to automatically receive their tracking info for the package

Answer (score 1):

For the e-mail part you don't need an extension. You can specify extra mail addresses thru System=>Configuration=>Sales e-mails that also need to receive the e-mail (specify multiple as a comma-separated list).